# SHA1 with BASE64 in java util class does not generate correct password

Tags: java, base64, sha1

I have written a util class in Java for webservice call. My util class creates the password digest required for a web service call.  This digest password is made up of: A digest password generated with the following algorithm:  `base64Encode(sha1Hash(<Nonce><TimeStamp><Secret>))`

My generated password does not equal to the generated password from the vendor's tool which uses the same algorithm (I don't have access to their code so I am not sure how that is implemented).  I am not sure if I did something wrong, can someone look over my code and see if I did something wrong with SHA1 encryption or Base64 encoding. Thanks for your help! Below is my code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class OminitureWSUtil {

private static MessageDigest SHA1;

static {
    try {
        SHA1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");

    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nae) {
        throw new RuntimeException(nae);
    }
}

static class OmniturePasswordDigest {
    private final String timestamp;
    private final String nonce;
    private final String secret;

    private String password;

    public OmniturePasswordDigest(String secret) {
        Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
        c.setTime(new Date());

        //timestamp =  DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c);
        //nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");

        timestamp = "2011-01-26T20:10:56Z";
        nonce = "MTkyMTYwZWMzMjIzZGJmYzNiYmE5M2E5";

        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public String getNonce() {
        return nonce;
    }

    public String generatePassword() {
        if(password == null) {
            String beforeEncryption = nonce+timestamp+secret;
            System.out.println("before encryption, encoding: " + beforeEncryption);

            try {
                SHA1.reset();
                byte[] toEncrypt = beforeEncryption.getBytes("UTF-8");
                //SHA1.update(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.length);
                SHA1.update(beforeEncryption.getBytes());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                throw new RuntimeException(uee);
            }

            byte[] encryptedRaw = SHA1.digest();
            byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedRaw);

            try {
                password = new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                throw new RuntimeException(uee);
            }
        }

        return password;
    }
}


public static OmniturePasswordDigest generatePasswordDigest(String secret) {
    return new OmniturePasswordDigest(secret);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OmniturePasswordDigest opd = generatePasswordDigest("1779ab07fb93a01e3d4a6ee174124b91");
    System.out.println("nonce: " + opd.getNonce());
    System.out.println("timestamp: " + opd.getTimestamp());
    System.out.println("password: " + opd.generatePassword());

    if("Lr+m+/6y3XUxvjd8Rtn75gqn/b4=".equals(opd.generatePassword())) {
        System.out.println("all good");
    } else {
        System.out.println("generated password is not the same, it should be: " + 
                "Lr+m+/6y3XUxvjd8Rtn75gqn/b4=");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Race of SHA1 visible from miles away. 
Change the code like that:

```
-SHA1.reset();
+MessageDigest SHA1= (MessageDigest) OminitureWSUtil.SHA1.clone();
```

Reset is just not what you need; Clone is intended for such cases.

btw, throwing any exception in the class init (static{}) kills the class and partly any other class referencing that class (so the entire [web]application). It's a bad practice, since the exception (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError) may get trapped somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I have rewritten it to create a new instance of MessageDigest per each getPassword method invocation instead. Would clone() be faster then instantiating MessageDigest each time via MessageDigest.getInstance()?

Comment: of course, for being faster :). "Clone is intended for such cases."... but well, you'd never/ever spot the difference on your right own; next this code:  `SHA1.update(beforeEncryption.getBytes());` is bad, either use the UTF-8 or some 8859_1 or whatever but do not depend on the system-wide encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is for the REST Api for Omniture? There is a working example on there site. However, your code does look right at first glance.

https://developer.omniture.com/java_rest_api

Also I don't know how you are going to use this class but SHA1 is not thread safe and if multiple thing calls generatePassword() you'll get some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to actually figure this out.  It seems that they are are encoding the Nonce in the xml message and that is what was throwing me off since I never encoded my nonce in the message.